# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to className

Tags: java, hibernate

**Code:**

```
public void getDetails() {
try {
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
String hql = "select c.mobile, c.password FROM CrbtSubMasterDemo c where rownum<20";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List<CrbtSubMasterDemo> itr = query.list();
session.getTransaction().commit();
for (CrbtSubMasterDemo pojo : itr) {//excepion line
System.out.println("[" + pojo.getMobile() + "]");
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

**CrbtSubMasterDemo** is pojo mapped with the db.
When I try to run it, it gives following Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.telemune.demoPojo.CrbtSubMasterDemo
at com.telemune.demoHibernate.QueryTester.getDetails(QueryTester.java:57)
at com.telemune.demoHibernate.QueryTester.main(QueryTester.java:23)
```

The question is query.list() is returning the list of objects of pojo class. Then why is this Exception. I am new to Hibernate, sorry if its a silly question.

Comment: @ v.ladynev please help sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir, Many times user faces this kinda requirements . Hibernate has ResultTransformer to convert a hql/sql in Object.

```
    public CrbtSubMasterDemo{
         private Stirng mobile;
         private String password;

          public CrbtSubMasterDemo(){
            --------------
         }

        #####after setting the transation set whichever columns you are selecting should be given as name of property of your object
        String hql = "select c.mobile as mobile, c.password as password FROM CrbtSubMasterDemo c where rownum<20";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        List<CrbtSubMasterDemo> itr = query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CrbtSubMasterDemo.class) ).list();
        ##No need to commit the transaction.
    }
```

It will convert you query into the CrbtSubMasterDemo

Comment: this was a real solution by the way. Can you give me where I can Explore my Criteria/Hibernate concepts?

Comment: @ sunixi please explain why we are not commiting the transaction here

Comment: You can use Criteria where you want restrictions.
Like
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(CrbtSubMasterDemo.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.lt("rownum", 20));
List<CrbtSubMasterDemo> list=cr.list();

Comment: and yashpal ji criteria will return all coulumns of your table . If you want only selected columns shud be returned then you need to use Projections >

Comment: well..I hope we could have a chat box. but sunixi JI I asked 1. why we are not comming the transaction. 2.Can you give me where I can Explore my Criteria/Hibernate concepts. :)   in refrence to    ##No need to commit the transaction.

Comment: Sir , you are doing select operation and commit means you have done some changes in database and after that you want to make it peramanent. and if you want revert it then use rollback.

Answer (score 3):

When you write this:

```
String hql = "select c.mobile, c.password FROM CrbtSubMasterDemo c where rownum<20";
```

Your result set is not a `List` of `CrbtSubMasterDemo`

Try to write:

```
String hql = "select FROM CrbtSubMasterDemo c where rownum<20";
```

Another way is define a new constructor of CrbtSubMasterDemo where you pass only two fields `c.mobile, c.password`

so your query becomes:

```
String hql = "select new " + CrbtSubMasterDemo.class.getName() + "(c.mobile, c.password) FROM CrbtSubMasterDemo c where rownum<20";
```

If you follow this solution, remeber to add a default constructor too (without parameters), so in your pojo you have:

```
public CrbtSubMasterDemo(String mobile, String password) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.password = password
}
```

and

```
public CrbtSubMasterDemo() {
}
```

Comment: @ JoeTaras may be I am using it wrong but it turned into:    ERROR:  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class  [com.telemune.demoPojo.CrbtSubMasterDemo]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.lang.String
 Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.lang.String

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj You need to add a constructor with two `String` arguments to the `CrbtSubMasterDemo`. And you need a default constructor too.

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj: I've updated my answer add a complete path of class. Another reaso can be if one of two fields are null. Yes, as has written v.ladynew, you must add a default constructor too (without parameters)

Comment: add space after new, sorry

Comment: @v.ladynev means I will need an exactly matching parameterized constructor for every different query?

Comment: If you want a variable number of fields yes, otherwise you can use the first solution (where you'll get all POJO rows, more expensely but is automapped)

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj It is not very convenient, of course. You can try to use a transformer http://in.relation.to/2006/03/17/hibernate-32-transformers-for-hql-and-sql/. You can transform directly to  `CrbtSubMasterDemo` without DTO.

Answer (score 3):

```
String hql = "select c.mobile, c.password FROM CrbtSubMasterDemo c where rownum<20";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
```

Result of this will be `List<Object[]>`

```
List<Object[]> itr = query.list();

for (Object[] row : itr) {
  System.out.println(String.format("mobile:%s, password:%s", row[0], row[1]));
}
```

if `mobile` and `password` are strings, of course. You can use a transformer to transform results directly to `CrbtSubMasterDemo`.

[Hibernate 3.2: Transformers for HQL and SQL](http://in.relation.to/2006/03/17/hibernate-32-transformers-for-hql-and-sql/)

[FluentHibernateResultTransformer](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/transformer/FluentHibernateResultTransformer.java)

Comment: yeah it worked...but can you please tell me.. what's the role of POJO it left with...I didn't use any getter of the class not even the object of pojo . How will I have the Idea that it is working on my POJO or not? thanks for help.

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj Don't clear understand what you ask about. For a query `from CrbtSubMasterDemo` you will have a `List<CrbtSubMasterDemo>`. For a query `select mobile, password FROM CrbtSubMasterDemo` you will have a `List<Object[]>`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not directly cast the result of "query.list();" to List of CrbtSubMasterDemo. As query.list() return object list. Iterate over the object list received and cast one by one to put in list List of CrbtSubMasterDemo