# ClassCastException with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am trying to fetch specific fields from my entities. I need the result in my entity structure.

Following are my entities:

**Country**

```
public class CountryModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CmtID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "CmtName")
    private String name;
    @JoinColumn(name="CmtStateID")
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=StateModel.class,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<StateModel> state;
}
```

**State**

```
public class StateModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "SmtID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "SmtName")
    private String name;
}
```

Following is the HQL query am executing:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select c.name, s.name from CountryModel c join c.state s where c.id=2");
CountryModel stateModel = (CountryModel) query.uniqueResult();
```

But am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.muziris.entity.CountryModel
```

Thanks for helping.

Expected result:

```
Country :
        name : india
        state : 
              name : kerala
              name : goa
        name : Pak
        state :
              name : karachi
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your classes are mapped you can try:

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("from CountryModel c where c.id=2");
 CountryModel countryModel = (CountryModel) query.uniqueResult();
```

Let's make use of the mapping and HQL.

From there you can use a DTO to have only the data that you need

```
public CountryDTO transform(CountryModel cm){
String countryName = cm.getName();
List<String> stateNames = cm.getState().stream.map(StateModel::getName)
                                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
return new CountryDTO(countryName, stateNames);
}
```

CountryDTO is the result that you need.

Comment: no. i only need to get country name and state name. i do not need all properties

Comment: still it will fetch all data from DB bro. i cannot allow that to happen.

Comment: why not? Why would you map your classes and use HQL then?

Comment: @tdavid Looks like `EAGER` loading is used. All related entities can be fetched if you will fetch entirely `CountryModel`.

Comment: Because in projects same entity is used in different places. in all places you would not want entire data. If u do that you are giving unwanted load to DB

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate returns `List<Object[]>` when you use the projections.
`List<Object[]>` is a list of specified projection columns.

Some links

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36883968/3405171

[How to transform a flat result set using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361256/how-to-transform-a-flat-result-set-using-hibernate/36361630#36361630)

Comment: will it work on non sql query. I cannot use native query